# Can Savings Plans be applied to AWS Workspaces?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing, amazon-workspaces, amazon-savings-plans

Savings Plans can be applied to EC2, Lambda, and Fargate, https://aws.amazon.com/savingsplans/ and WorkSpaces are EC2 instances behind the scenes. Can Savings Plans be applied to AWS Workspaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it cannot. Confirmed with AWS Support. Even though WorkSpaces are EC2 instances behind the scenes, Savings Plans cannot be applied to WorkSpaces.